# update website_id and store_id using sql command

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, sql, server-setup

i'm going to move all customers to one site from an other site, i planned to use sql command to do this

```
Update customer_entity set website_id = 4 where website_id = 3
```

but when i ran this command, there is an error

## 1062 - Duplicate entry 'someone@email.com-4' for key 'UNQ_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_EMAIL_WEBSITE_ID'

there is an email duplicated and a unqiue key disallowed me to perform this action.

Any ideas to solve this?

***Re:i run the script but there is an error***

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mage_Customer_Exception' with message 'This customer email already exists' in /home/prd1/public_html/app/Mage.php:580 Stack trace: #0 /home/prd1/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Customer.php(99): Mage::exception('Mage_Customer', 'This customer e...', 3) #1 /home/prd1/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(1122): Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer->_beforeSave(Object(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer)) #2 /home/prd1/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer)) #3 /home/prd1/public_html/au_asia.php(16): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save() #4 {main} thrown in /home/prd1/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 580
```

Answer (score 0):

try this SQL Command :

```
UPDATE `customer_entity` SET `website_id` = '4' WHERE `customer_entity`.`website_id` = '3' AND `customer_entity`.`email` != 'someone@email.com-4';
```

**OR**

Add bellow code in `test.php` file at magento root folder and run in browser

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app('default');
class AR
{
    public function index()    
    {
        $currentWebsiteId = 3;
        $updateWebsiteId = 4;
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('website_id', $currentWebsiteId);
        foreach($collection as $customer) {
            $customer->setWebsiteId(2); 
            $customer->setId($customer->getId());
            $customer->save();
        }
    }
}
$obj = new AR();
$obj->index();
?>
```

Comment: there are not only one someone@email.com, may be someone1*@email.com exists

Comment: i need to update all customers, there will be so many sql i need to use email by email

Comment: Updated ans pls check now

Comment: i run the script above it gives me "Server error 500"

Comment: this is the final solution i found 
update customer_entity set website_id = 4 where website_id = 3 AND email in (select tt.email from (SELECT email FROM `customer_entity` where website_id in (3,4) group by email having count(email) <= 1) as tt)

Answer (score 0):

I found the OP's solution to work where I needed to move only customers belonging to a particular Customer Group

```
UPDATE customer_entity SET website_id = 4, store_id = 4 
WHERE website_id = 3 AND group_id = 9 AND email IN 
(SELECT tt.email FROM (SELECT email FROM customer_entity WHERE website_id IN (3,4) 
GROUP BY email HAVING count(email) <= 1) AS tt)
```